# Update project from Laravel 5.8 to 6 or 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

I am beginner in Laravel. I make my project in Laravel 5.8. Now I want update it. I have this composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
        "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~4.0",
        "darryldecode/cart": "~4.0",
        "evilnet/dotpay": "^2.1",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.4",
        "geocoder-php/nominatim-provider": "^5.1",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "mews/captcha": "^2.2",
        "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0",
        "php-http/message": "^1.7",
        "spatie/laravel-cookie-consent": "^2.6",
        "torann/laravel-meta-tags": "^3.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-ckeditor": "^4.7",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "repositories": {
        "packagist.org": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packagist.org"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/psCMS/Functions/create_thumb.php",
            "app/psCMS/Functions/correct_image_orientation.php",
            "app/psCMS/Functions/import_csv.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want update my project to Laravel 6 or 7.

I make this command:
composer update

but it's return me error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.17.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.15.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.14.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.13.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.12.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.11.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.10.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.0.0
    - unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.37], illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - unisharp/laravel-ckeditor 4.7.2 requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.37], illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v5.8.37].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework 6.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0].
    - Installation request for unisharp/laravel-ckeditor ^4.7 -> satisfiable by unisharp/laravel-ckeditor[4.7.2].
```

How can I repair it?

Is posible make this update?
unisharp/laravel-ckeditor - works with Laravel 5 and 6....

Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Laravel-ckeditor documentation](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor)  `unisharp/laravel-ckeditor` supports on `Laravel 5.*` version.

To use this package with Laravel 6 you need to install ckeditor manually.

Copy all ckeditor files to `public/ckeditor` directory and copy/paste this code to end of your blade template where you want to use ckeditor. But this may not always work efficiently.

```
<script src="{{ asset('ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```